# More than only one methods to authentication middleware on laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, middleware

I am having this on my laravel project and i want to add more methods to the exept array. And i could not figure it out how i should write it?

```
public function __construct()
    {
    $this->middleware('auth', [ 'except' => 'index' ]);

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just add such an array like that:

```
public function __construct()
    {
    $this->middleware('auth', [ 'except' =>['index','fooAction'] ]);

    }
```

You can see more about here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#controller-middleware

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do not understand how i could be so stupid, i tried everything except this one.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public function __construct()
{
$this->middleware('auth', [ 'except' => ['index','home'] ]);

}
```